# STL's power in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++11, numeric

I've found STL's [`power`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/power.html) in the `numeric` header that computes `power(TYPE T, Integer a)` in O(log(a)), but when I've written that and compiled it with `g++` it gave me compile error and says `error: ‘power’ was not declared in this scope`. Why it happens? I know writing the power function that computes in O(log(N)) is easy buy I want to know if there is a ready function in C++'s standard libraries. Isn't any feature added in C++11 standard?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use std::pow, which is part of C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the page you link:

> This function is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard.

While the SGI-documentation is often helpful, be aware that it contains several deviations from the standard.

Answer (score 8):

That function was in SGI's original STL, but isn't in the standard library.

In the GNU library, it's available as an extension, `__gnu_cxx::power` in `<ext/numeric>`.

Comment: @Farzam: Include the header, and call the function.

Answer (score 5):

No there's no `std::power` or similar algorithms in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

In the [`<cmath>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) header there are several overloads for the standard numeric types. Is there a particular reason you need a templated version?

Comment: You can also add comments to the question.

Comment: Certainly, I figured a power function he _can_ use might be useful as an answer as well.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: for example, if you have a class matrix and define multiple(*) operator on it, if you have a matrix A, power(A, N) could be computed using only log(N) multiplications.